# In any finite metric space, singletons are both closed and open?

Tags: general-topology

I think the question explains itself, but i’ll explain anyways:
Some times i get that every finite subset in a metric space is closed and some other times i get that subsets of finite metric spaces (and hence, unions or intersections of “open” singletons) are open. Maybe the subsets of finite metric spaces are both closed and open? Is this what the “clopen set” is?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: A finite metric space must be discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The word 'clopen' is a mathematical notion. A set is clopen iff it is closed and open.
- Yes, if a metric space is finite, all subsets are both closed and open.
- There are much more examples of clopen sets, not only finite subsets. For example any subset of $\Bbb N $ or the subset $(0,1)$ in $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Minor quibble: "clopen" isn't slang at all, it's a technical term.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, maybe, but it sounds horrible so I don't consider it a proper word. I prefer using 'both closed and open'.

Comment: I actually like it myself, but more to the point it's consistently used in the mathematical literature, so regardless of personal feelings the ship has sailed.

Comment: @NoahSchweber alright, I've hidden my attitude to this word in the pocket and changed the answer.

Comment: I might be making this up, but I swear that, at one point in undergrad, the word "clopen" was used to describe the basis sets $[a,b)$ for the Sorgenfrey line. For the record, though, I feel like it's best to just either say "closed and open" or define "clopen" for the sake of non-english speakers.